# Understanding ls */ -d

Tags: directory, ls, wildcards

`*` means all files and directories including files in sub directories.

`/` means in root directory

`ls */` brings files in sub directories in current directory (not includes files in current directory)

`ls -d` list directory entries instead of contents. 
My directory full of files and sub directories. Why in my case this brings only `./` ?

By adding all together I have `ls */ -d`. It brings all directories in current directory. What is logic of this combination? If I take separate parts of this command listed it not brings such result.

Answer (score 6):

`/` doesn't mean root directory. It's a path separator. If the path *begins* with `/`, then of course, you have an absolute path, which starts at the root level. Here, the slash comes after `*`. The asterisk globs all the entries of the current directory, but here, the pattern is `*/`: everything in the current directory that ends on a `/`; files don't end on `/`, but ending a path with a slash means you specified a directory, so this only means directories. Compare with `*.txt` which would mean all entries ending with `.txt`.